# My enterprise javabean project can't be deployed

Tags: java

I have been doing ejb project on netbeans and each time I finished building the newsApp on the ntbeans documentation, I get the same error of not being able to deploy the app. I have confirmed my glassfish is running. I'm using JDK 17 and glassfish version 6.2.5.

I was expecting it to deploy well since I followed all the instructions to the latter.Anyone to help me please. Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIyqY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.